# Calculating LD50 in R, different values than in SAS

Tags: r, sas

I'm trying to calculate the LD50, LD90, and LD95 of insects exposed to a compound. My issue is that I'm getting different values using different programs and am struggling to find where my code is different. I'm using the ecotox package in R for the LC_probit function.

Here is what my data looks like

```
Dose Mortality Number
10 12 12
1 8 12
0.5 10 12
0.1 9 12
0.05 11 12
0.01 0 12
0.005 0 12
0.001 0 12
```

Prior to COVID, I had access to a computer that had SAS installed, and this is the code I used (with my data included)

```
data CPB;
input conc mort;
number=12;
datalines;
10 12
1 8
0.5 10
0.1 9
0.05 11
0.01 0
0.005 0
0.001 0
0 0
;
*proc sort;
proc probit data=CPB log10 optc inversecl plots=(predpplot ippplot);
model mort/number=conc;
output out=new p=p_hat;
proc print;
run;
```

And here is the code I've been using for R (I made sure not to use the control dose in NJ_48 as that is what the documentation for LC_probit says to do)

```
NJ_48_probit = LC_probit((Mortality / Number) ~ log10(Dose), data = NJ_48, p = c(50,90,95), weights = Number, het_sig=0.1)
```

For LD50, 90, and 95 values, SAS gives 0.03092, 0.55951, and 1.27153, while R gives 0.0665, 0.909, and 1.91. Where is this discrepancy coming from?

Comment: The data has a bunch of points around y = 0 and the others are around y = 1 so it is going to be difficult to get meaningful fit.  The middle part of the S will be going almost vertical.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having the same problem even with data that is more linear along the dose gradient. I understand that with the data in clumps are extreme y's that fit might be weird, but I don't understand how the two programs would calculate that fit differently when they both cite the same probit sources.

Comment: When you run your code in SAS you would have gotten warnings, how did you resolve those?

Comment: I don't think I ever noticed any (I'm very unfamiliar with SAS), so I guess I ignored them? What kind of errors would it have given?

Answer (score 0):

Running your code in SAS produces the following warnings in the log.

> WARNING: The relative gradient convergence criterion of 0.5340102335 is greater than the limit of 0.0001. The convergence is questionable.
>
> WARNING: The procedure is continuing in spite of the above warning. Results shown are based on the last maximum likelihood iteration. Validity of the model fit is questionable.

The first warning is even reproduced on the results page:
[Warning from results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw6o1.png)

It would suggest that it was not able to converge effectively. In those cases where the convergence is not attained I don't think we should expect SAS and R to produce the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Not withstanding the convergence error, you are trying to fit two different models in `SAS` and `R`.

The model in `SAS` includes the natural response threshold **C** as specified by the `optc` argument.

**Mortality/Number = C + (1-C) × Φ( a + b(log10(Dose)) )**

While that in `R` does not include the natural response threshold **C**.

**Mortality/Number = Φ( a + b(log10(Dose)) )**

If you do not include natural response threshold **C** both `R` and `SAS` give the same results.

```
data CPB;
input conc mort;
number=12;
datalines;
10 12
1 8
0.5 10
0.1 9
0.05 11
0.01 0
0.005 0
0.001 0
0 0
;

proc probit data=CPB log10 inversecl plots=(predpplot ippplot);
model mort/number=conc;
output out=new p=p_hat;
proc print;
run;
```

| Parameter | Estimate |
| --- | --- |
| Intercept | 1.3285 |
| Log10(conc) | 1.1285 |

```
data <- data.frame(conc = c(0, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 10),
           mort = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 9, 10, 8, 12),
           number = 12)
data$conc[data$conc == 0] <- 0.000000001

mod1 <- glm(formula = "mort/number ~ log(conc, 10)", 
            family = binomial(link = "probit"), 
            data = data,
            weights = data$number)

mod1

## Call:  glm(formula = "mort/number ~ log(conc, 10)", family = binomial(link = "probit"), 
##     data = data, weights = data$number)
## 
## Coefficients:
##   (Intercept)  log(conc, 10)  
##         1.329          1.129  
## 
## Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  7 Residual
## Null Deviance:       102.7 
## Residual Deviance: 26.92     AIC: 40.84

coef(mod1)

##   (Intercept) log(conc, 10) 
##      1.328508      1.128505
```